# Does gsutil cp use batch uploads to upload multiple files at once?

Tags: storage, gsutil

I know that gsutil cp can operate in parallel to speed things up, but I will be uploading a lot of small files, and am trying to minimize my per-request overhead. Does gsutil automatically batch multiple file uploads into a single batch request?

(I'm referring to this batch feature here)
https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, gsutil doesn't currently do this. However, if you run gsutil with the -m flag, it will operate in multi-threaded mode, which will upload your files in parallel.